# How to do a JAX-WS SOAP Web Service call

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws

Can you please let me know how to do a Java SOAP webservice (JAX-WS) call. For example , I want to send below headers to the url https://example.com/eai_enu/WSSOAP=1 and get the response. Sharing an example code will be really helpful. Thank you in advance.

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://siebel.com/WebService">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <UsernameToken xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">XXXXXXX</UsernameToken>
    <PasswordText xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices"></PasswordText>
    <SessionType xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">Stateless</SessionType>   
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <web:QuerySR_Input>
     <web:SRNum>450545194</web:SRNum>
  </web:QuerySR_Input>
     </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: At minimum you are missing the [SOAPAction](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383527) header.  What language are you using to create and send the request?  Your question as it is written is very broad.

Comment: I am using Java. Can you please Share me an example John